# Get locations using Zipcode

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to get **Location** based on the **zipcode** using a **Google Maps Javascript API**.

**For example** : I will have an input in page. When user enter any zip-code and send request the corresponding location should be given in a response.

Kindly, tell me that it can be done? If yes then how? I tried but couldn't get the task done.

Thanks.

Comment: You need a data source that can provide that. Asking about external resources is off topic here

Comment: I am not asking about the external resources.

Comment: I am asking that can we get location using zip code using the Google MAP API?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps Geocoding API provides waht you are looking for.
You can try it in the developers documentation for geocoding:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro